# Postgresql 9.4 clusters not auto starting on Debian

Tags: debian, postgresql, debian-jessie, postgresql-cluster

I have Debian 8.2 x64 and Postgresql 9.4 (from repo). I've recreated default cluster in different location like this:

```
# service postgresql stop
# pg_dropcluster 9.4 main
# pg_createcluster -d /srv/postgresql/data/9.4/main 9.4 main -- -W -A md5
# service postgresql start
```

and then I can connect to the database with:

```
# psql -WU postgres
```

then I've created another cluster with:

```
# pg_createcluster -d /srv/postgresql/data/9.4/apps -p 5433 9.4 apps -- -W -A md5
```

I can start it with:

```
# pg_ctlcluster 9.4 apps start
```

and connect:

```
# psql -WU postgres -p 5433
```

but the init script starts only the `main` cluster ignoring `apps` and acording to the man pages if `/etc/postgresql/9.4/apps/start.conf` doesn't exists it is assumed to auto start cluster. But this is my `/etc/postgresql/9.4/apps/start.conf`

```
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

auto
```

so it should also start `apps` cluster or did I misunderstand something or there should be some other options set ?

**UPDATE**

Well I think I've fixed my problem with:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-common
```

and after this all clusters are controlled by the init script, and:

```
# service postgresql start|stop|restart
```

or

```
systemctl start postgresql.service
```

affect all clusters. It's weird cause first installation and reinstallation didn't report any errors.

Comment: If you're using systemd, you might find useful to read `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.systemd` (online on http://sources.debian.net/src/postgresql-common/173/systemd/README.systemd/)

Comment: I experienced the same - and it fixed itself when I did the apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-common.